# Detect if the page is refreshed (reload) or window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a timer function, and I need to continue the timer when the page the page is refreshed, and make an ajax call when the page is closed (this is working). How can I do this?

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function setTimer(timeSpent) {    
        $.post('./modules/ajax/task.php', {time:timeSpent}, function(data) {    
            $('#timer').timer({
                seconds: data.timerTime
            });

            if(!isNaN(timeSpent)){
                $('#timer').timer('remove');
            }
        }, 'json');    
    }    
    setTimer('start');

    $(window).on('blur', function() {
        setTimer($('#timer').data('seconds'));
    }).on('focus', function() {
        setTimer('resume');
    }).unload(function() {
        var timer     = $('#timer'),
            timeSpent = timer.data('seconds'),
            userID    = timer.data('userid'),
            taskID    = timer.data('taskid');

        $.post('./modules/ajax/task.php', {
            timeSpent: timeSpent, 
            userID: userID, 
            taskID: taskID, 
            save: 'save'
        }, function(data) {})
    });
});
```

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` event is called before the page is unloaded, but there's no built in mechanism to know if the page is being refreshed, the browser/tab was closed, or the user navigated to a different page. A better solution would be to store the static end date (either locally or remotely) and countdown to that date, regardless of what state the page is in

Comment: `make an ajax call when the page is closed (this is working)` Could work on local server but not on remote one, for sure

Answer (score 0):

Use `onbeforeunload` event which is called Before page is refreshed,Tab is closed or browser is closed.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Any string';
};
```

You  can run this script from browser console and check result.